# Start REPL with definitions loaded from file

Tags: raku

Is there a way to start the Perl 6 REPL with definitions loaded from a file?

I.e. let's say I have this in `test.p6`:

```
sub abc() { say 123; }
```

I'd like to be able to start the perl6 REPL and load that file so that I can use `abc` interactively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the easiest way would be to put your code in a .pm6 file, e.g. `./Foo.pm6`, mark the subroutines in question with `is export` and then start Rakudo Perl 6 like this:

```
$ perl6 -I. -MFoo
To exit type 'exit' or '^D'
> abc
123
```

Comment: Thanks Elizabeth.