# How can you create Perl 6 REPL plugins?

Tags: read-eval-print-loop, raku

Perl 6 [comes with a REPL](https://www.learningperl6.com/2016/10/15/experiment-in-the-perl-6-repl/); and that REPL picks up plugins such as [Linenoise](https://github.com/hoelzro/p6-linenoise) as soon as it's installed, getting all the goodies.
However, it's not clear to me how Linenoise plugs into the REPL to provide that functionality. I haven't seen it documented anywhere, either. If I want to create my own plugin for providing, let's say, other type of tab completion (which Linenoise already has, but far as I can tell, only for keywords), or anything else for that matter, how could I proceed? Is there any particular part of Linenoise I could fork for doing that?
This would help, for instance, towards providing [a better REPL](https://github.com/perl6/user-experience/issues/2), as the community has requested for some time already.

Comment: `git grep Linenoise` -- https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/b7190f649747486896cf2c399797dfd1cd883876/src/core/REPL.pm6#L205-L211 -- As you can see this isn't a public plugin API.

Comment: Is this similar to my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50119972/perl6-repl-usage ?

Comment: @JasonDoege there's some relation, but I was looking for something along the lines of adding functionality to the REPL and using it automatically without calling any other method or module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You currently cannot, at least not without patching Raku. It's hard-coded in Raku's source code.